# Table rate not working if I change the title

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

If I change the shipping method title from the CMS (and clear the cache and storage), from "Table Rate" to "Testing" for example, and change

`$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway')
            ;`

to

`$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('testing_bestway')
            ;`

Then the shipping sum always returns 0. The same happens if I change `Best Way` instead of `Table Rate`. Why is this happening? And how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you just need to change the title, do it from admin. Don't modify method in code. They are unique to every shipping method and changing them would need changing their appearance throughout the carrier.

Comment: I changed it in the admin. But don't I need to change the code to match what I changed in the admin?

Comment: No, that's why it's their in admin.